# Recorrer un datetable para colorear una celda según una condición

Tags: c#

```
public void Repeater1_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

            //if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            //{
            //    foreach (Control c in e.Item.Controls)
            //    {
            if (RepeaterItem is Label)
            {
                // Grab label
                Label Label10 = (Label).FindControl("CONVERSION_TOTAL"); //c as Label;
                Double valor = Convert.ToDouble(Label10.Text);

                if (valor > 4.0)
                {
                    Label10.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    Label10.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }

                //       }
                //   }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si colocas el error, la duda o lo que es la intención en tu planteamiento se te apoye servirá para aportes.

Comment: La idea es que al momento que carge el datetable una fila de registro cambia de color dependiendo si es sobre 4% sea verde y si es bajo 4% sea  rojo entonces lo primero que hize fue recorrer la tabla para luego ver que registro scumple la condicion se entiende?

Comment: se trata de un desarrollo asp.net, no ?

Comment: si @LeandroTuttini

Comment: @user37452 colocalo como parte del planteamiento; no  en comentarios. No omitas detalles como: me marca error (colocar el error), termina sin error pero no se reflaja el cambio de color, nunca entra a "x" condición y si hay registro/valores que la cumplen, etc....

Answer (score 1):

Lo que noto es que no haces uso del FindControl() para localizar el Label dentro del Item del repeater

Ademas si usas el evento OnItemDataBound, no realizas un foreach

[Cómo: Utilizar el evento ItemDataBound del lista controles de Web Forms de .NET Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/es-ar/help/317582/how-to-use-the-itemdatabound-event-of-web-forms-list-controls-in-visual-c-.net)

si quieres acceder al dato usarias

```
DbDataRecord dbr = (DbDataRecord)e.Item.DataItem;
```

y si quieres acceder al label seria

```
((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblContactName")).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

el item del repater no es un label por lo tanto el if que defines no pasara nunca, debes buscar usando quizas algo como ser

```
Label label10 = e.Item.FindControl("CONVERSION_TOTAL") as Label;

if(label10 != null){

   label10.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```